# Need to generate non duplicate numbers in 2 different columns in VBA

Tags: vba

Im pretty stuck with something, especially as i can not use the MRand function for the random numbers that i need to be in 2 different columns.

Column A (Par1) will just have a number from 1 To 99 (add +1 for each entry)
The program then will choose randomly only 1 of the selected range in col.A 1 to 99 and put in col.B (Par2), this must not be a duplicate.

Then in col.C (Par3) its the same thing, however the value can not equal to the col.B either.

Is it possible to generate it like this, especially column C that can be equal to col.B

best regards Peter

Edit:

Oh sorry, Column B and C can not be equal to column A either

Comment: Oh sorry, Column B and C can not be equal to column A either

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
Sub Macro1()

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Step 1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range("B1", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), Range("B" & i).Value) > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Column B Row " & i & " duplicate!"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Thanks you but as im pretty new dont get the result in col.B

Comment: Sub RandomB()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Step 1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range("B2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)), Range("B" & i).Value) > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Column B Row " & i & " duplicate!"
    End If
Next i


End Sub

Comment: changed it a little bit but maybe made a misstake

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. The code I posted pop up a messagebox to show dublicate values in B Column...

Answer (score 0):

oh sorry

Column A will have the specific values range 1 To maybe 99

Column B will randomly take this range and populate B:B but they cant be equal to col.A on the same row.

Col.C will also randomly take col.A but can not be equal to col.A or Column B, and the result should be put into col.C

Answer (score 0):

think ill specify a little

In column A it will just be a number starting from 1 to XXX, this will be +1 for each new line entry.

The mission is to have like 99 couples, where each couple has to invite 2 other couples for 2 out of 3 chriterias (Starters-main course-dessert).

In turn they will be invited to 2 other couples for 2 out of the 3 chriterias.

So column A will be the Couple 1 that will invite Column B and column C for one of the 3 chriterias if it makes sence :)

Answer (score 0):

Made a quick code, hope its what u need

```
 Sub LoopNCheck()

Dim lngCount As Long
Dim lngLastRow As Long
lngLastRow = 99

For lngCount = 1 To lngLastRow
   With Range("a" & lngCount)
    .Value = lngCount
    .Offset(0, 1) = Getrandom(lngCount, lngLastRow)
    .Offset(0, 2) = Getrandom(lngCount, lngLastRow, .Offset(0, 1))
   End With
Next


End Sub

Function Getrandom(lngRestriction As Long, lngMax As Long, Optional lngSecRestriction As Long = 0)

Calculate:
Getrandom = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, lngMax)

If Getrandom = lngRestriction Or Getrandom = lngSecRestriction Then GoTo Calculate

End Function
```

Comment: Do i need to change something?, i get an error that a value in the formula is of the wrong data type

Comment: ive checked it on my site and it works, where exactly the error appears?